# Regex: How to use same tag to identify end of match and beginning of another match

Tags: regex

I'd like to make a global regex statement that captures a text in a document such as:

```
[ITEM]
   Text 1.
[ENDLIST]
```

The following will capture the text "Capture group 1."

```
/\[\[ITEM\](.+)\[ITEM|ENDLIST\]/g
```

However, as the list grows, the regex fails for:

```
[ITEM]
   Text 1.
[ITEM]
   Text 2 (fails to capture here, as well as all subsequent even cases).
[ITEM]
   Text 3.
[ENDLIST]
```

This is because the first match will use the first `[ITEM]` to begin the match and the second `[ITEM]` to end the match. This prevents the second `[ITEM]` from being used to begin the second match. In the case above, text 1 is captured, text 2 is not, and text 3 is captured.

How would I write a regex to work with the expanded example above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `/\[ITEM]\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\[(?:ITEM|ENDLIST)])/g`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1jdGFJ/1).

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to use look ahead but that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lookahead for the `[ITEM]` or `[ENDLIST]` tag - it will end the current group when finding the tag for the next group, without moving the cursor forward, which allows the tag to also begin the next group.

```
\[ITEM\](.*?)(?=\[(?:ITEM|ENDLIST)\])
```